# $n$-th derivative of exponential integral

Tags: derivatives, special-functions, exponential-function

I would like to adapt Abramowitz and Stegun [5.1.27](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_230.htm) formula to my problem.

Equation 5.1.27 states:

$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left[e^z\,E_1(z)\right]=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[e^z\,E_1(z)\right]+\frac{(-1)^n\,(n-1)!}{z^n}$$

In my case I have:

$$e^{az}\,E_1(az)$$

so to have the $n$-th derivative I am thinking of doing:

$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left[e^{az}\,E_1(az)\right]=a^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[e^{x}\,E_1(x)\right]$$

Is it right? Can I just scale by the prefactor? 
Has someone any idea to prove or disprove it? And maybe help me with the right derivation in my case?

Comment: Why does yours start with $z$ on the LHS, but then show $x$ on the RHS?

Comment: @Amzoti That is my way (probably wrong) to rewrite my case similarly to A&S formula ($x=az$).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In general, if

$$g_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$$

then by induction with the chain rule,

$$a^ng_n(ax)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(ax)$$